# Limit IAM User to specific VPC only

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc, amazon-iam

I have two VPC's in my account.  One for DEV and One for Production.  I want to create a IAM User which, the user should only see the DEV EC2 instances in the console and should able to create or reboot the instances.  He should not able to see the Production EC2 instances. I tried with bellow policy and got error as 
`"An error occurred fetching address data: You are not authorized to perform this operation."`
My IAM Policy...

```
 {
        "Version": "2012-10-17",
        "Statement": [
            {
                "Action": [
                    "ec2:Describe*",
                    "ec2:RebootInstances",
                    "ec2:RunInstances",
                    "ec2:CreateTags"
                ],
                "Effect": "Allow",
                "Resource": "*",
                "Condition": {
                    "StringEquals": {
                        "ec2:Region:VPC": "us-west-2:vpc/vpc-00000000"
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    }
```

I could able to do some thing here with the policy bellow.  But not able to apply the Tags.  The thing is User should not able to rename any other Tags other tags in PRODUCTION VPC when I insert the bellow rule then user could able to change the Tags of Other VPC instances as well ...

```
 {
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Action": "ec2:CreateTags",
    "Resource": [
    "*"
    ]
    }
```

Here is my current rule which can read other VPC instances but only readonly. I am fine with it.  But I am not able to create the instances with Tags...

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "NonResourceBasedReadOnlyPermissions",
            "Action": [
                "ec2:Describe*",
                "ec2:CreateKeyPair",
                "ec2:CreateSecurityGroup",
                "iam:GetInstanceProfiles",
                "iam:ListInstanceProfiles"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "IAMPassRoleToInstance",
            "Action": [
                "iam:PassRole"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:iam::818755641843:role/EC2LaunchVansDEV"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "AllowInstanceActions",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ec2:RebootInstances",
                "ec2:RunInstances",
                "ec2:StartInstances",
                "ec2:AttachVolume",
                "ec2:DetachVolume",
                "ec2:CreateTags"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:ec2:us-west-2:818755641843:instance/*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "ec2:InstanceProfile": "arn:aws:iam::818755641843:instance-profile/EC2LaunchVansDEV"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Sid": "EC2RunInstances",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ec2:RunInstances",
                "ec2:CreateTags"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:ec2:us-west-2:818755641843:instance/*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "ec2:InstanceProfile": "arn:aws:iam::818755641843:instance-profile/EC2LaunchVansDEV"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Sid": "EC2RunInstancesSubnet",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ec2:RunInstances",
                "ec2:CreateTags"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:ec2:us-west-2:818755641843:subnet/*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "ec2:vpc": "arn:aws:ec2:us-west-2:818755641843:vpc/vpc-5b0f3c3f"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Sid": "RemainingRunInstancePermissions",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "ec2:RunInstances",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:ec2:us-west-2:818755641843:volume/*",
                "arn:aws:ec2:us-west-2::image/*",
                "arn:aws:ec2:us-west-2::snapshot/*",
                "arn:aws:ec2:us-west-2:818755641843:network-interface/*",
                "arn:aws:ec2:us-west-2:818755641843:key-pair/*",
                "arn:aws:ec2:us-west-2:818755641843:security-group/*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Sid": "EC2VpcNonresourceSpecificActions",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ec2:DeleteNetworkAcl",
                "ec2:DeleteNetworkAclEntry",
                "ec2:DeleteRoute",
                "ec2:DeleteRouteTable",
                "ec2:AuthorizeSecurityGroupEgress",
                "ec2:AuthorizeSecurityGroupIngress",
                "ec2:RevokeSecurityGroupEgress",
                "ec2:RevokeSecurityGroupIngress",
                "ec2:DeleteSecurityGroup",
                "ec2:CreateTags"
            ],
            "Resource": "*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "ec2:vpc": "arn:aws:ec2:us-west-2:818755641843:vpc/vpc-5b0f3c3f"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The `DescribeInstances` action cannot be limited by a `ec2:Vpc` condition. In fact it is part of a set of API actions that do not allow Resource level permissions, see a full list here:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/ec2-api-permissions.html#ec2-api-unsupported-resource-permissions

I believe you're best bet is to separate into multiple accounts and have the separation occur there.

See also:

- https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/iam-policy-restrict-vpc/
- http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-supported-iam-actions-resources.html

Comment: Not Worked.  When I open EC2 console... I am getting this error.... "An error occurred fetching instance data: You are not authorized to perform this operation."

Answer (score 0):

Right now it is impossible without additional tricks e.g. by tags because these actions [do not support](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/ec2-api-permissions.html) VPC in conditions:

```
RebootInstances
StartInstances
StopInstances
TerminateInstances
```

But all of them support region in conditions, so you may want to move dev environment to specific region.